# How to calculate total hours in my Timesheet model?

Tags: python, django

I'm setting two models, Timesheet and TimesheetEntry. TimesheetEntry will be inline and is set it in admin.py file and from there you can put the current hours per project. My question is how to make function and calculate the total_hours so I can visualize it in my custom table in Django template ?

````
class TimesheetEntry(TimeStampedModel):
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name=_("Hours"))
    timesheet = models.ForeignKey('timesheet.TimeSheet', verbose_name=_("Timesheet"),
                                  related_name='timesheet_entries', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey('project.Project', verbose_name=_("Project"),
                                related_name='timesheet_entries', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    project_role = models.ForeignKey('project.ProjectRole', verbose_name=_("Project role"),
                                     related_name='timesheet_entries', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.timesheet} - {self.project} - {self.project_role}"

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.timesheet.save()
        super().save(**kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Timesheet entry")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Timesheet entries")


class Timesheet(TimeStampedModel):
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today, editable=True)

    total_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("Total hours"), editable=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='timesheet')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} - {date_format(self.date, 'DATE_FORMAT')}"

    def recalculate(self):
        self.total_hours = self.timesheet_entries.all().aggregate(total_hours=Sum('hours'))['total_hours'] or 0

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.recalculate()
        super().save(**kwargs)

    def projects(self):
        from hr.project.models import Project

        return Project.objects.filter(
            pk__in=self.timesheet_entries.all().values_list('project_id', flat=True).distinct()
        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Timesheet")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Timesheets")
    ```
````

Comment: have you tried adding a property to your model? `@property` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Comment: I have never used this, because I'm a bit new.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... where you will get to try new things... definitely recommend reading the associated docs.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple and complex at the same time. You can use a `@cached_property` decorator on a model method (like the `recalculate` - which you could rename `total_hours` and remove it from your `save` method) and then cache the result of the `cached_property` - only to invalidate it each time there is a new or edited time entry - by deleting the `cached_property`. [Cached Property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property)

```py
class Timesheet(TimeStampedModel):
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today, editable=True)

    total_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("Total hours"), editable=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='timesheet')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} - {date_format(self.date, 'DATE_FORMAT')}"

    @cached_property
    def total_hours(self):
       return self.timesheet_entries.all().aggregate(total_hours=Sum('hours'))['total_hours'] or 0

    def save(self, **kwargs):

        super().save(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is not what you want to use here as you are summing it up on the instance. so this should do it:

```
    self.total_hours = sum(self.timesheet_entries.all().values_list("hours",flat=True)
```

Then you either make this a property (As pointed out by Icognos) or you override the save function and call recalculate in the save function.

Answer (score 0):

Well this `def recalculate` in Timesheet model works when is made an editing. The real problem were that I need to callback in Timesheet Serializer and there I have to call the function `timesheet.recalculate` and `save` it. In both ways it works from the support answers. Thank you !

````
class TimesheetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    timesheet_entries = TimesheetEntrySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Timesheet
        fields = ['date', 'user', 'total_hours', 'timesheet_entries']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super().to_representation(instance)
        result['user'] = UserDetailsSerializer(instance=instance.user).data
        return result

    def create(self, validated_data):
        entries = validated_data.pop('timesheet_entries')

        timesheet = Timesheet.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for entry in entries:
            TimesheetEntry.objects.create(timesheet=timesheet, **entry)

        timesheet.recalculate()
        timesheet.save()

        return timesheet
    ```
````